# Converting Array of Objects into Array of Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

There is a condition where i need to convert Array of objects into Array of Arrays.

Example :-

```
arrayTest = arrayTest[10 objects inside this array]
```

single object has multiple properties which I add dynamically so I don't know the property name.

Now I want to convert this Array of objects into Array of Arrays.

P.S. If I know the property name of object then I am able to convert it. But i want to do 
     dynamically.

Example (If I know the property name(firstName and lastName are property name))

```
var outputData = [];
for(var i = 0; i < inputData.length; i++) {
    var input = inputData[i];
    outputData.push([input.firstName, input.lastName]);
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this:

```
var output = input.map(function(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).sort().map(function(key) { 
    return obj[key];
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Sabof.
I got it what i wanted.
Actually I am working on a jQuery Datatable so for your help i get the data. Now i need Property name for Datatable columns heading.

Can you tell me how i can get single object's property name??

Comment: @user3292436 Just use this bit: `Object.keys(obj).sort()`

Comment: hi Sabof. I solved my problem but i couldn't understand the logic behind of MAP method. I have searched on google and found some answer (Its return an array and etc.) but couldn't understand.
Can you please explain??

Comment: @Mohit `map` creates a new array, where each item is the result of `function` applied to an item in the original array

Comment: Hi @sabof, is the sort important here? Can I skip it if I don't want to alter the order of my values?

Answer (score 36):

Converts Array of objects into Array of Arrays:

`var outputData = inputData.map( Object.values );`

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Best answer. Thanks.

Comment: Only thing, I had to collect keys from obj and then added using `unshift` to insert into first position! Otherwise, perfect oneliner!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `for-in` loop

```
var outputData = [];
for (var i in singleObject) {
    // i is the property name
    outputData.push(singleObject[i]);
}
```