# How to append checked/unchecked checkbox values to post data

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc

In JavaScript (the use of jQuery is acceptable), how would I turn something that is an array of objects:

```
// Array of objects.
var myArray = [ { code: "X", selected: true }, { code: "Y", selected: false }, { code: "Z", selected: true } ];
```

Into a two-dimensional array of values?:

```
var myArray[0][0] = "X";
myArray[0][1] = true;
myArray[1][0] = "Y";
myArray[1][1] = false;
myArray[2][0] = "Z";
myArray[2][1] = true;
```

---

I ask because I'm having some trouble sending data in an AJAX call that combines serialized form data with an array of objects.

I need all of the data to map to a View Model server-side:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        selectedRelatedTaxes = new List<RelatedTax>();
    }

    public string co { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string taxCode { get; set; }
    public List<RelatedTax> myArray { get; set; }
}

public class RelatedTax
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public bool selected { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the JavaScript function that tries to wrangle all the data together:

```
function GetAllData() {
    var result = {};

    if (!$('#FormID'))
        return {};

    result = $('#FormID:not(input[data-function="partOfArray"])').serializeArray();

    var myArray = [];
    $('input[data-function="partOfArray"]').each(function (index) {
        var code = $(this).val();
        var selected = $(this).is(':checked');

        myArray.push({ code: code, selected: selected });
    });

    if (result) {
        result.push({ name: 'myArray', value: myArray });
    }

    return result;
}
```

If I use the above function, I get this for the data in the AJAX call:

[image: All of the data necessary for the call. This will not map properly to the list server-side.]

The array doesn't map properly to the list server-side.

If I use this JavaScript function instead:

```
function Test() {
    var myArray = [];
    $('input[data-function="partOfArray"]').each(function (index) {
        var code = $(this).val();
        var selected = $(this).is(':checked');

        myArray.push({ code: code, selected: selected });
    });

    return { myArray: myArray };
}
```

I get this for the data in the AJAX call:

[image: Only the array being sent in the AJAX call. This will map properly to the list server-side.]

The array does map properly to the list server-side. But of course this lacks all other pieces of data.

What is the format of the data in the second picture? It looks like a two-dimensional array to me. How do I get my array of data into that format, alongside all the other data?

Here is the code that makes the AJAX call:

```
function LoadAddCompanyTaxWizard(url) {
    var formData = GetAllData();

    $.ajax(
        {
            cache: false,
            method: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: formData
        },
        .error(...)
        .success(...),
        .complete(...)
    );
}
```

Comment: The problem is somewhere else. Post the code that posts data to server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Array of Objects into Array of Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22477612/converting-array-of-objects-into-array-of-arrays)

Comment: There are a lot of good answers below about how to transform from an array of objects to an array of arrays. But it's not clear looking at the rest of the code why you aren't making the array you want in the first place. Why aren't you just using `Array.push([code,  selected ])` to begin with?

Comment: @SalmanA I've included the function that makes the AJAX call.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I do apologize that the title does make it a duplicate. Changing the title to reflect the true underlying issue would probably be for the best, although I really don't know what to put for the title.

Comment: @MarkMeyer In my JavaScript functions (Line 14 in GetAllData and Line 7 in Test), am I not using Array.push()?

Comment: @MaxJacob you are using `Array.push` but you are pushing in an object making an array of objects, when it seems you want an array of arrays.

Comment: @MaxJacob I used your array as the `input` in the accepted answer to that duplicate question and got the same output as the desired output you show in your question.

Comment: @Max see revised answer. It does seem to serialize the form, then append checkbox values-checkbox selected pairs to the array. But post variables `selectedRelatedTaxes[0][code]=...` look weird to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to revise the code as follows:

```
function GetAllData() {
  // check if an element exists
  if ($('#FormID').length === 0) {
    return {};
  }

  // use the :not filter correctly
  var result = $('#FormID input:not([data-function="partOfArray"])').serializeArray();

  $('#FormID input[data-function="partOfArray"]').each(function(index) {
    var code = $(this).val();
    var selected = $(this).is(':checked');
    result.push({
      name: "selectedRelatedTaxes[" + index + "][code]",
      value: code
    });
    result.push({
      name: "selectedRelatedTaxes[" + index + "][selected]",
      value: selected
    });
  });

  return result;
}
```

Here is my attempt at replicating the form:

```js
function GetAllData() {
  // check if an element exists
  if ($('#FormID').length === 0) {
    return {};
  }

  // use the :not filter correctly
  var result = $('#FormID input:not([data-function="partOfArray"])').serializeArray();

  $('#FormID input[data-function="partOfArray"]').each(function(index) {
    var code = $(this).val();
    var selected = $(this).is(':checked');
    result.push({
      name: "selectedRelatedTaxes[" + index + "][code]",
      value: code
    });
    result.push({
      name: "selectedRelatedTaxes[" + index + "][selected]",
      value: selected
    });
  });

  return result;
}

$("#FormID").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(GetAllData());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="FormID">
  <input name="category" value="State">
  <input name="co" value="CT0002">
  <input name="taxCode" value="AK">
  <input name="selectedRelatedTaxes" data-function="partOfArray" type="checkbox" value="AKSUI" checked="">
  <input name="selectedRelatedTaxes" data-function="partOfArray" type="checkbox" value="AKSUI-E">
  <input name="selectedRelatedTaxes" data-function="partOfArray" type="checkbox" value="FOO" checked="">
  <input name="selectedRelatedTaxes" data-function="partOfArray" type="checkbox" value="BAR">
  <input type="submit" value="Test Script">
</form>
```

Comment: This worked for me!
It mapped everything properly server-side.
https://i.imgur.com/TgC5Uip.png

Comment: Yes, it was an XY problem I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Just `map` the array:

```js
var myArray = [ { code: "X", selected: true }, { code: "Y", selected: false }, { code: "Z", selected: true } ];

var result = myArray.map(({code, selected}) => ([code, selected]));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @mhodges isn't your edit just a copy of my answer? (I answered 3 minutes before your edit)

Comment: Ah, didn't see that. For the record, it was only 2 minutes xD

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very simply using `.map()` and `Object.values()`, like so:

```js
var myArray = [ { code: "X", selected: true }, { code: "Y", selected: false }, { code: "Z", selected: true } ];

console.log(myArray.map(obj => Object.values(obj)))
```

If you need to guarantee the order of the items in your array, you can do the following:

```js
var myArray = [ { code: "X", selected: true }, { code: "Y", selected: false }, { code: "Z", selected: true } ];

console.log(myArray.map(({code, selected}) => [code, selected]))
```

The downside to the second approach is that it is not dynamic, and you will have to explicitly order each element you want in the array. But it is much safer in terms of consistent output.

Since you didn't use ES6 in your question, a non-ES6 version would look like this:

```
myArray.map(function (obj) {
  return [obj.code, obj.selected]
});
```

Comment: Will `Object.values()` guarantee the correct order?

Comment: @MarkMeyer No, [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) will return the values in an arbitrary order, so it can’t be relied on for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I would use reduce, twice.

1. Reduce the main array.
2. Reduce the object using it's keys
3. Push the reduced object values onto the current array

```js
var myArray = [ { code: "X", selected: true }, { code: "Y", selected: false }, { code: "Z", selected: true } ];

let result = myArray.reduce((arr, itm, idx) => {
  arr.push(Object.values(itm).reduce((a, i) => a.concat(i), []))
  return arr
}, [])

console.log(result[0][0])
console.log(result[0][1])
console.log(result[1][0])
console.log(result[1][1])
console.log(result[2][0])
console.log(result[2][1])
```

Comment: This will not always work. You cannot rely on [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to return an array of values in the order `[code, selected]` – it returns values in an arbitrary order. To be safe you would have to explicitly reference the `code` and `selected` keys of the object and put them in the same order each time.

Comment: Isn't this overcomplicating it a lot?!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could create your 2d array in the JS

```
var myArray = [];
    $('input[data-function="partOfArray"]').each(function (index) {
    var code = $(this).val();
    var selected = $(this).is(':checked');
    myArray.push([code, selected]);
});
```

This will create the array you described:

```
var myArray[0][0] = "X";
myArray[0][1] = true;
myArray[1][0] = "Y";
myArray[1][1] = false;
myArray[2][0] = "Z";
myArray[2][1] = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solutions in ES6 you can find here a lot.

**Solution in ES5**

```js
var myArray =
[
    {code: "X", selected: true},
    {code: "Y", selected: false},
    {code: "Z", selected: true }
];

var newArray = myArray.map(function(obj){return [obj.code, obj.selected]});

console.log(JSON.stringify(newArray, null, '\t'));
```

Comment: I have an ES5 solution in my answer as of 34 minutes ago

Comment: @mhodges, O_o, unfortunately without snippet I didn't see it.