# How to convert json format into arrays in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, list

I am having csv data which i converted into json data and using in react.js project. Below is the sample of json file have.

```py
export const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    Word: "AN",
    Target: "Female",
    Weight: 0,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    Word: "Aaron",
    Target: "Female",
    Weight: 0,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    Word: "Abbey",
    Target: "Female",
    Weight: 0,
  }
```

But i want to convert the above data into below format in react.js. How can i do it

```py
const sankeyData = [
  ["Word", "Target", "Weight"],
  ["AN", "Female", 0],
  ["Aaron", "Male", 0],
  ["Abbey","Female", 0],
];
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? Note neither of those things is JSON, but either could be represented in it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have used https://csvjson.com to convert my csv file into json format. But i was now unable to convert them into square brackets

Comment: Again neither your input nor output is JSON. And by "into square brackets" you mean creating arrays, that should make it easier to research what is a pretty trivial task.

Comment: Please read the description of the JSON tag: _"Do not use this tag for native JavaScript objects or JavaScript object literals."_ Please don't spam tags. This question is unrelated to React.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22477694/212869

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the function with this code.

```
function convertFormat(data) {
  if (data.length === 0) return [];

  let new_data = [];
  let key_data = [];
  Object.keys(data[0]).map((key) => {
    if (key !== 'id') key_data.push(key);
  });
  new_data.push(key_data);

  data.map((item) => {
    let new_item = [];
    Object.values(item).map((value, index) => {
      if (index !== 0) new_item.push(value);
    });
    new_data.push(new_item);
  });
  return new_data;
}
```