# Covert key-value javascript object into array format

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access java script object which is available in the below format:

```
[
  {'To':'A','From':'X','Weight':5},
  {'To':'A','From':'Y','Weight':7},
  {'To':'A','From':'Z','Weight':6},
  {'To':'B','From':'X','Weight':2},
  {'To':'B','From':'Y','Weight':9},
  {'To':'B','From':'Z','Weight':4}
]
```

How can I access above object to create array like below ?

```
[
  [ 'A', 'X', 5 ],
  [ 'A', 'Y', 7 ],
  [ 'A', 'Z', 6 ],
  [ 'B', 'X', 2 ],
  [ 'B', 'Y', 9 ],
  [ 'B', 'Z', 4 ]
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting Array of Objects into Array of Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22477612/converting-array-of-objects-into-array-of-arrays)

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can use array method `.map()`

```js
let arr = [
  {'To':'A','From':'Y','Weight':7},
  {'To':'A','From':'Z','Weight':6}
]

let result = arr.map(Object.values)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I see error as - property 'map' does not exist on type Promise<any>

Comment: the data you provided is an "array" not a "promise" tho.

Answer (score 4):

You can

- Use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

  ```
  const arrOfArrs = arr.map( Object.values );
  ```
- Use Lodash's [_.map()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#map) and [_.values()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#values) in the same manner:

  ```
  const _ = require('lodash');
  . . .
  const arrOfArrs = _.map( arr , _.values );
  ```

You should, however, be aware that the order in which an object's properties are iterated over (and hence returned) is ***not*** guaranteed in any way by the Ecmascript/Javascript standard. It can vary from Javascript implementation to implementation, and can even change from execution to execution. The most common order in which things are returned is insertion order, but that's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 4):

Use a map function:

```js
const l = [
  {'To':'A','From':'X','Weight':5},
  {'To':'A','From':'Y','Weight':7},
  {'To':'A','From':'Z','Weight':6},
  {'To':'B','From':'X','Weight':2},
  {'To':'B','From':'Y','Weight':9},
  {'To':'B','From':'Z','Weight':4}
]

const newArray = l.map(el => [el.To, el.From, el.Weight])
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let a = [{'To':'A','From':'X','Weight':5},{'To':'A','From':'Y','Weight':7},{'To':'A','From':'Z','Weight':6},{'To':'B','From':'X','Weight':2},{'To':'B','From':'Y','Weight':9},{'To':'B','From':'Z','Weight':4}]
let array = []

for(i in a){
    let temp = [a[i]['To'], a[i]['From'], a[i]['Weight']]
    array.push(temp)
}

console.log(array)
```

Comment: This may not the best answer but it looks like works ok

Answer (score 1):

You could use this to ensure the correct order of items in inner array.

```js
let arr = [{'To':'A','From':'X','Weight':5},{'To':'A','From':'Y','Weight':7},{'To':'A','From':'Z','Weight':6},{'To':'B','From':'X','Weight':2},{'To':'B','From':'Y','Weight':9},{'To':'B','From':'Z','Weight':4}]

let result = arr.map(obj => [obj.To, obj.From, obj.Weight]);
console.log(result);
```